# ¿Cómo dividir una imagen en 4 tonos diferentes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow, rgba

Estoy tratando de hacer que una imagen se divida en las tonalidades: rojo, verde, azul y gris (escala de grises).

Hasta el momento solo he conseguido hacer que la imagen entera se cambie a un solo tono, pero mi objetivo es que se divida en 4 cuadrantes y cada uno tenga un tono diferente.

Adjunto el código en donde puedo mostrar la imagen con un solo tono:

```
    from PIL import Image

    img = Image.open("imagen.jpg")
    layer = Image.new('RGB', img.size, "blue")
    salida = Image.blend(img, layer, 0.5)
    salida.show()
```

¿Alguien podría aconsejarme? No sé de qué manera dividir la imagen con los tonos que requiero, ya he intentado modificar el código anterior pero no he tenido éxito.

Adjunto una imagen de ejemplo a lo que me refiero, una disculpa si no fui muy clara antes.

[image: Los cuatro tonos que deseo lograr]

Comment: No tengo claro si desea dividir por tono (es decir, color) o por geometría (es decir, cuadrantes). ¿Podría proporcionar una entrada representativa y las imágenes de salida correspondientes, por favor? Gracias.

Comment: Esto conlleva bastante trabajo y me parece que no es una pregunta específica en la que se ha investigado y probado. Primero iría por partes: investiga como se puede dividir una imagen en *X* trozos, después tienes que investigar como se cambia el color de cada una de los trozos y por último ver como puedes unirlas de nuevo.

Comment: @JohnDoe ya incluí una imagen, una disculpa si no me expliqué bien.

Comment: @RubialesAlberto tal vez deba ver todo por separado. Checaré algunas cosas así :c gracias

Comment: Pero cada uno de los trozos coloreados se obtiene simplemente "poniendo encima" un filtro del color correspondiente? O se trata de extraer las componentes RGB respectivamente de los pixeles subyacentes?

Comment: como acá chillan por todo te aconsejo que dividas la imagen en cuatro con .crop() que es uno de los métodos que trae pil donde en una tupla guardas(izquierda,arriba,derecha,abajo) , y lo repetis para cada parte ,después que este cortada las unis con .paste() y finalmente la guardas con .save()

Answer (score 0):

Tenga en cuenta que lo que está haciendo es simplemente agregar una superposición azul en lugar de dividir en tonos.

Supongo que esto es lo que realmente quieres:

```
from PIL import Image

FILENAME = 'imagen.jpg'

# Split into layers
img = Image.open(FILENAME).convert('RGB')
R, G, B = img.split()
Z = Image.new('L', img.size, 'black')
RZZ = Image.merge('RGB', (R, Z, Z))
ZGZ = Image.merge('RGB', (Z, G, Z))
ZZB = Image.merge('RGB', (Z, Z, B))
gray = img.convert('L')

# Create an image with quadrants
res = Image.new('RGB', (2*img.size[0], 2*img.size[1]))
res.paste(RZZ, (0,0))
res.paste(ZGZ, (img.size[0], 0))
res.paste(ZZB, (0, img.size[1]))
res.paste(gray, (img.size[0], img.size[1]))
res.thumbnail(img.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)        # optional: resize to the original size
res.show()

res.save('res.png')
```

Este seria su resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Answer copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64909704/5407270) without attribution. Notice that you need to provide attribution according the license CC BY-SA.